# how to move the cursor to a specific coordinates in pywinauto?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I need to automate the cursor to go to a specific coordinates.
`pywinauto.mouse.move(coords=(100,100))` isn't working. giving error as

> mouse is not a part of a module.

```
from pywinauto import application,findwindows,mouse 
import pywinauto 
import win32api 

pywinauto.mouse.move(coords=(100,100)) 
#on the above line it gives error.
```

Should I import something else too for mouse?

Comment: What code did you try, and where did it fail?

Comment: Please share you code in the question, not in comments. To learn more about how to ask a question on Stack Overflow, please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 3):

Since you imported module mouse explicitly, just use

```
from pywinauto import mouse
mouse.move(coords=(100, 100))
```

`import pywinauto` doesn’t import mouse by default. We’re planning to fix it later.

Comment: I tried to run this code but still Error is coming as "Global name 'mouse' is not defined.

Comment: It usually means that `from pywinauto import mouse` is missing in your code. Also it looks different in my case when I remove the import: `NameError: name 'mouse' is not defined`. Can you provide more details: Python version, pywinauto version and full traceback? Not only error message, but the whole call stack.

Comment: I suspect your code has more lines than posted in the answer. So `import traceback; traceback.print_exc()` may be useful, if you catch the exception in `try-except` block. Just edit your question to improve its quality.